# ActionLink executing multiple times

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have an ajax action link which is appending a partial to a div.

```
$('#hypNewCriteria').click(newClick);
...
var newClick = (function ()
{
    console.log('newClick');
    $.ajax(this.href, {
        success: function (result)
        {
            ...
        }
}
```

On the first page load and on every partial that is returned I am (probably unnecessarily), am executing via a document.ready

```
$('#hypNewCriteria').click(newClick);
```

... subsequent clicks on the actionlink; the number of partial views returned increases by 1 each time. After 7 clicks, it returns 8 partials. I expect only 1 partial to append.

I suspect the .click(newClick) event is appending. Is there a way to set just one click event or clear the event before I set another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's unbind() method to unbind events.

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

I would also look into the live() jQuery method. This binds an event to all current and future elements that are added to a page, useful for pages that load partials or add items that require events to be added all the time.

Comment: No problem. I don't think that one() is what you're looking for. That would make an event only fire once and unbind itself. If you want the links to be clickable multiple times, that will make the link unreactive after the first click.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$('#hypNewCriteria').one('click', newClick);
```