# Jquery : how to remove unbind("click")

Tags: jquery

How can I remove the 'unbind' after using it? I need to enable back the click event.
below my function.

1.This function is to disable the print link

```
function edit(){
$("#ENQUIRY_VIEWMETER a.print").addClass('ui-state-disabled').unbind("click");
}
```

2.to enable the link to be clickable.

```
function reset(){
$("#ENQUIRY_VIEWMETER a.print").removeClass('ui-state-disabled').bind("click");
}
```

Is there other method so that I can enable the link to be click again?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596909/actionlink-executing-multiple-times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using new Jquery 1.7 [`On()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)  and [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) methods, you can achieve this like in following... For further details plz read [Usage with Examples](http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/)

**off():**

```
$('#ENQUIRY_VIEWMETER a.print').off("click");
```

Or

```
('#ENQUIRY_VIEWMETER').off('click', 'a.print');
```

**on():**

```
$('#ENQUIRY_VIEWMETER a.print').on('click', handleClick);
```

Comment: i already update my jquery and also use .off()its working fine. but how to use .on() ?

$('#ENQUIRY_VIEWMETER a.print').on("click",handleClick);

this is my code, but it not functioning.

Answer (score 1):

Cache your code for the event in a variable and use event namespaces. Also use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) since `bind()` is deprecated.

```
var foo = function () { ... }

$el.on('click.foo', foo) // Bind event `foo` on click

$el.off('click.foo') // Unbind `foo` events attached to `click`
$el.off('.foo') // Unbind all `foo` events

$el.on('click.foo', foo) // Bind again
```